# Couldn't match type ‘HandlerSite m0’ with ‘HandlerSite m’ when "modifying" field with same value

Tags: haskell, ghc, yesod, yesod-forms

I'm working on a Yesod app and wanted to have an alternative `textField` with a modified `fieldView`. To start, I tried this:

```
textField
  :: ( Monad m
     , RenderMessage (HandlerSite m) FormMessage
     )
  => Field m Text
textField = I.textField
    { fieldView = fieldView I.textField
    }
```

As far as I can see, this `textField` should be identical to `I.textField`. However, I get the following error:

```
Foo.hs:37:19: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘HandlerSite m0’ with ‘HandlerSite m’
      Expected type: FieldViewFunc m Text
        Actual type: FieldViewFunc m0 Text
      NB: ‘HandlerSite’ is a type function, and may not be injective
      The type variable ‘m0’ is ambiguous
    • In the ‘fieldView’ field of a record
      In the expression: I.textField {fieldView = fieldView I.textField}
      In an equation for ‘textField’:
          textField = I.textField {fieldView = fieldView I.textField}
    • Relevant bindings include
        textField :: Field m Text
          (bound at Foo.hs:36:1)
```

Interestingly, this alternative way of writing this works just fine:

```
textField
  :: ( Monad m
     , RenderMessage (HandlerSite m) FormMessage
     )
  => Field m Text
textField = f
    { fieldView = fieldView
    }
  where
    f@Field {..} = I.textField
```

Is the problem in using `fieldView` as a function? I'm quite stumped right now. I tried using `ScopedTypeVariables` to link `m` to `m0`, but it didn't work and I don't see why it would even be needed. What's stopping `m` from matching with `m0`?

EDIT: I just tried:

```
textField
  :: ( Monad m
     , RenderMessage (HandlerSite m) FormMessage
     )
  => Field m Text
textField = I.textField
    { fieldView = fieldView
    }
  where
    Field {..} = I.textField
```

And it failed, so I guess the problem is related with mentioning `I.textField` twice. This is weird. It's not like `I.textField` is a type-class member with multiple definitions to select from, and, even if it were, I don't see what's stopping ghc from deducing that `m` and `m0` are the same.... ok `HandlerSite` is a type family, so I guess from the type checker's point of view it could lead to different instances of `RenderMessage` and so different definitions of code that's somehow linked to `I.textField`. I think I'm starting to see the light.

EDIT 2: I thought I could link them like this:

```
textField
  :: ( Monad m
     , RenderMessage (HandlerSite m) FormMessage
     )
  => Field m Text
textField = (I.textField :: Field m Text)
    { fieldView = fieldView (I.textField :: Field m Text)
    }
```

with `ScopedTypeVariables` on, but apparently not.

EDIT 3: Following the logic, this works:

```
textField
  :: ( Monad m
     , RenderMessage (HandlerSite m) FormMessage
     )
  => Field m Text
textField = f
    { fieldView = fieldView f
    }
  where
    f = I.textField
```

So I guess this has something to do with top-level vs local bindings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And it failed, so I guess the problem is related with mentioning I.textField twice. This is weird.

Actually, this is quite common when type families are involved. Let me show the issue in a simpler case. Suppose we have a type family as follows

```
type family F a
type instance F Int  = String
type instance F Bool = String
```

Note how `F Int` and `F Bool` are actually the same type, i.e. `String`. This is possible since `F` can be a non-injective function.

Now, if we have at hand the following function

```
foo :: F a -> SomeResultType
```

we discover that we can not, in general, call it as

```
foo "some string"
```

Why? Well, the compiler can not determine what type to use for `a`: it could be `Int` or `Bool`, since both would make `F a` to be `String`. The call is ambiguous, so it raises a type error.

Even worse, if we used *twice* that call in our code, e.g.

```
bar (foo "string") (foo "string")
```

it would be even possible to choose `a = Int` for the first call, and `a = Bool` for the second call!

Moreover, consider what would happen if we have a polymorphic value which can produce *any* `F a`.

```
x :: forall a . F a
```

Then, we might be tempted to call `foo x`. After all, `foo` takes `F a` and `x` can produce `F a` for any `a`. It looks fine, but it is once again ambiguous. Indeed, what should be chosen for `a`? Many choices apply. We might try to fix this with a type signature

```
foo (x :: F Int)
```

but this is completely equivalent to any of

```
foo (x :: String)
foo (x :: F Bool)
```

so it does really choose the type `a`!

In your code, a similar problem happens. Let's dissect the type error:

```
Couldn't match type ‘HandlerSite m0’ with ‘HandlerSite m’
    Expected type: FieldViewFunc m Text
    Actual type:   FieldViewFunc m0 Text
NB: ‘HandlerSite’ is a type function, and may not be injective
```

This is telling us that at some point we need to specify a `FieldViewFunc m Text`. This type involves a type family `HandlerSite m`, which due to non-injectivity, could be the same type as `HandlerSite m0` for some other monad `m0`.

Now, `I.textField` can produce a value "for any `m`". Hence, using it is somehow similar to using `foo x` above. Your code is more peculiar, since if we use the "same" call to `I.textField`, the compiler is able to infer that we indeed want the "right" `m`. Here, "same" call means defining some identifier like your `f` to `I.textField`, and use `f` twice. Instead, making two calls to `I.textField` allows GHC to choose two distinct `m`s, one for each call, and ambiguity arises.

If you are confused, don't worry -- it is a bit tricky to understand, especially on a relatively real-world framework like Yesod.

How to solve this? There are many ways, but in my opinion, the best, modern way to resolve such ambiguities is to turn on the `TypeApplications` extension (beyond `ScopedTypeVariables`) and then specify that we really want to choose `m` as the outer `m`, as follows:

```
textField :: forall m . 
     ( Monad m
     , RenderMessage (HandlerSite m) FormMessage
     )
     => Field m Text
textField = I.textField @ m
    { fieldView = fieldView (I.textField @ m)
    }
```

The `@ m` syntax is used to choose the type, overriding the type inference engine. It has a similar effect as writing a type annotation in many cases, but works even in "ambiguous" cases where type annotations do not. For instance `foo (x @ Int)` would have worked in the simpler example above.

(I'm not familiar with Yesod so the above might not work if `I.textField` is also parametrized by other type variables, in which case we need more `@ type` applications e.g. `I.textField @type @type2 ...` one of which is `@m`.)

Comment: Thank you, now it makes perfect sense. The function `fieldView` extracts a function value that only uses `m` for resolving `HandlerSite m` and that's what makes it potentially different from `textField`'s `m`. I imagine that if the return value of that function were `WidgetT (HandlerSite m) m ()` instead of the `WidgetT (HandlerSite m) IO ()` that it is, then this wouldn't have happened. The change you proposed worked after activating `TypeApplications` and `ScopedTypeVariables`. I only needed to add parentheses around the first application to avoid syntax error with an unexpected `{`.

Comment: I just noticed that another way to solve this is by using just `ScopedTypeVariables` like I was trying to originally in the question. I was only missing adding a `forall m.` to `textField`'s type signature, which I didn't realize was necessary to add the variable to the scope. Still, `TypeApplications` seems very cool.

Comment: Also, either way, linking the `m`'s of the first mention of `I.textField` is not necessary because it uses `m` in another manner besides passing it as argument to a type family, and that causes it to be well linked already. I'm making these comments to the benefit of future readers.

Comment: @JoL Note that you can answer your own question with the solution you ended up with. SO's policy allows that, precisely for the benefit of future readers.

Comment: Well, the point of this question was to understand what was going on rather than finding a solution, since I had already found a workaround, albeit without understanding why it worked, when I asked the question. I don't think I can explain what happened better than you did right here.